# Unable to keep datatable columns fixed despite having set it

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables, bootstrap-5

I've made a datatable and want to keep first and last columns fixed but despite specifying it doesn't seem to work.

Also while at it how do I set the last column to have 1-2 buttons ?

This is my html of the table

```
<div class="container text-nowrap " >
          <h1 class="text-center">Ideas</h1>
          <table class="table table-hover table-bordered mb-0 " id="newideastable">
            <thead >
              <tr class="text-center" >
                <th  style="background-color: #009879;">No.</th>
                <th>Title</th>

                ....... other rows

                <th>Published Date</th>
                <th style="background-color: #009879;">Options</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
          </table>
</div>
```

And this is my jquery for it

```
let table = new DataTable('#newideastable', {
    scroller: true,
    scrollX: true,
    scrollY: false,
    pagingType: "full",
    fixedColumns: {
          left: 1,
          right: 1
      },
    "language": {
          "paginate": {
                  page: 'Page %d',
                  pageOf: 'of %d',
                  info: 'Displaying records %d - %d of %d',
                  infoEmpty: 'No records to display',
                  infoFiltered: '(filtered from %d total records)',
            }
      },
      "ajax": {
        "url": "/ideas",
        "dataSrc": "",
        "type": "GET",
        "dataType": "json"
      },
      
      "columns": [
        { "data": "idea_number" },
        ...... other data
        { "data": "date" }
      ],
      "createdRow": (row, data, dataIndex) => {
            $(row).addClass("table-info");
            $(row).on('click', function() {
                setideamodal(data.idea_number);// sets a pop up bootstrap modal
            });
      }
    // options
  });
```

I'm using bootstrap 5.3, jquery 3.6.4 and datatables 1.13.4 all from CDN I got from their respective websites.

Comment: You can download all the required libraries from the DataTables [download](https://datatables.net/download/index) page. When I do that, your fixed columns functionality works for me. Also, you need to make sure that the browser page width is narrow enough to actually show the horizontal scroll bar - otherwise, you will not see the fixed column logic in action.

Comment: "_Also while at it how do I set the last column to have 1-2 buttons ?_" - Please try to ask only one question at a time.

Comment: @andrewJames ok will edit the question and ask as a different one. thanks will try downloading instead of using CDN.

Comment: The download page can provide links to resources. Take a look. The point is to use _compatible libraries_ which is the main reason for visiting the download page.

Comment: @andrewJames thanks it works perfectly now. Like you said I had probably got incompatible libraries.